# Anaconda Navigator doesn't launch Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter, anaconda3

I'm really new to coding (I graduated in Economics and trying to learng Python, with no prior experience) and just downloaded Anaconda to start my apprenticeship.
Since my user in the "C:" directory has one space between my name and my surname, I create a new folder in "C: > Anaconda" to install the program. I ran the installer as administrator and selected this folder as destiny.
After the installation was finished, I tried launching Jupyter Notebook from the Anaconda Navigator. Then I can see a message "Launching notebook" on the bottom of the navigator, along with a loading bar. However, it disappears and nothing happens.
I read some other topics here with people with the same problem as mine but none of the solutions worked for me. When I try lauching Jupyter Notebook from the Anaconda prompt I receive the following message:

```
Read the migration plan to Notebook 7 to learn about the new features and the actions to take if you are using extensions.

https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrate_to_notebook7.html

Please note that updating to Notebook 7 might break some of your extensions.

[W 12:11:52.005 NotebookApp] Loading JupyterLab as a classic notebook (v6) extension.
[C 12:11:52.005 NotebookApp] You must use Jupyter Server v1 to load JupyterLab as notebook extension. You have v2.5.0 installed.
    You can fix this by executing:
        pip install -U "jupyter-server<2.0.0"
[I 12:11:54.615 NotebookApp] The port 8888 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 12:11:54.627 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\Tomás Mello
[I 12:11:54.627 NotebookApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.5.4 is running at:
[I 12:11:54.627 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8889/?token=c212526e4794b6e54e3e00c5cb3581bb97497b5b5775efe9
[I 12:11:54.627 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8889/?token=c212526e4794b6e54e3e00c5cb3581bb97497b5b5775efe9
[I 12:11:54.627 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 12:11:54.665 NotebookApp]

    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///C:/Users/Tom%C3%A1s%20Mello/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-25888-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8889/?token=c212526e4794b6e54e3e00c5cb3581bb97497b5b5775efe9
     or http://127.0.0.1:8889/?token=c212526e4794b6e54e3e00c5cb3581bb97497b5b5775efe9
```

Can you help me out? I'm sorry if I commited any grammar mistakes (english is not my native language) and if any further explanation is necessary please let me know.

Cheers!

I tried checking if there was any problem in the files that were installed and couldn't find anything that seemed unusual (but again, I'm not experienced in identifying installation bugs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everyone goes through this, it's great that you are trying, you can also try visual studio code, it is fairly simple too, might need some video tutorial to set it up.

Regarding this issue, did you try follow the steps in the anaconda prompt?

You can copy the links mentioned in any browser of choice. Like Google Chrome, Microsoft edge etc.

Copy paste this into the browser

```
http://localhost:8889/?token=c212526e4794b6e54e3e00c5cb3581bb97497b5b5775efe9
```

Or this one

```
http://127.0.0.1:8889/?token=c212526e4794b6e54e3e00c5cb3581bb97497b5b5775efe9
```

Pretty sure it would open jupyter notebook.

Comment: And it seems your jupyter server needs updating too. For that just copy the code "pip install -U "jupyter-server<2.0.0" in the anaconda prompt. And it will update.

Comment: It worked, man. Thank you very much! I'll start my journey, wish me luck hahaha